# What is correlation between access token life time and Refresh token life time in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to understand correlation between access token life time and refresh token life time in
sliding token expiration of OAuth 2.0? In what I researched by now answers are confusing and sometimes contradicting. Some says that, for example, if access token life time is 15 minutes and refresh token life time is 2 hours, user is able to use application for two hours without reentering credentials. Some other says that it is possible only if periods of inactivity of the application are no longer than 15 minutes. Third says that user can use application endlessly as long periods of inactivity are les than 15 minutes. I would highly appreciate if someone can offer an ultimate answer or point me to the the source where I can find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [latest OAuth 2.1 refresh token specs](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-07.html#section-4.3) describe the standards based behaviour. There is a fixed lifetime represented by the refresh token lifetime configured. During this time, additional rotated refresh tokens may be issued, but this does not affect overall expiry. The user only needs to re-authenticate when this time expires.

All good authorization behaviours implement the standards based behaviour. As a convenience, some systems may also implement additional custom behaviour, for sliding expiry. The client settings will then include a maximum lifetime to prevent an indefinite session. The details will be explained in the vendor docs.

Session expiry due to lack of activity can be done at the application level fairly easily. Eg, keep track of the time of the last API call, and run a timer that checks if an idle session time has expired. If so, discard all tokens, and prompt the user to start a new login. This can use the OpenID Connect `prompt=login` parameter to override any SSO sessions and force re-authentication.